# Python Hacker Rank Two Way Emunese Translator

Tags: python, python-3.x

This problem asks me to make a two way translator, English to Emunese(made up language) and Emunese to English - I have to take the last letter from each word and move it to the front of the word, add mu after each word, and add emu after every three words (ie. 'imu odmu tnomu emu wknomu whomu otmu emu odmu sthimu' is the English sentence 'i do not know how to do this' translated to Emunese and of course the opposite for when I'm converting the sentence to English). At first I thought this would be relatively simple. Through my own test it seems to run fine, change the sentence to Emunese and you'll see that it converts to English. The problem occurs when I plug the code into Hacker Rank. Again, the code seems to run fine on the visible test cases (Ones where I can see the output and input). The problem occurs on the hidden test cases, where two of the test cases return 'Wrong Answer'. I've been scratching my head trying to figure out what my code is missing, but I cant quite think of it.

Here is the Hack Rank link:
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hcpc19-div-i/challenges/hcpc-19-div-i-two-way-emunese-translator

This code can be plugged in anywhere (Under this is code that can be plugged directly into hacker rank):

```
sentence = ['i', 'dont', 'know','how', 'to', 'do','this']
#Which version you want to convert the sentence to
lang = 'EMU'
n = len(sentence)

if lang == 'ENG':
    #Move the last letter to the front
    sentence = " ".join([words[-1:] + words[:-1] + 'mu' for words in sentence])
    result = []

    #Add emu after every three words
    for idx, word in enumerate(sentence.split()):
      if idx > 1 and idx % 3 == 0:
        result.append("emu")
      result.append(word)

    #If sentence is 3, 6, 9, etc letters long add emu to the end
    if n % 3 == 0:
      result.append("emu")

    sentence = " ".join(result)

    print(sentence)

elif lang == 'EMU':
    sentence = ' '.join(sentence)

    #Get rid of mu and emu
    sentence = sentence.replace('mu', '')
    sentence = sentence.replace('e ', '')

    #Move the first letter to the end of the word
    print( " ".join([words[1:] + words[0] for words in sentence.split()]))
```

This code has to be plugged into Hacker Rank to work (Look up for a version that can be plugged in anywhere):

```
if lang == 'ENG':
    #Move the last letter to the front
    sentence = " ".join([words[-1:] + words[:-1] + 'mu' for words in sentence])
    result = []

    #Add emu after every three words
    for idx, word in enumerate(sentence.split()):
      if idx > 1 and idx % 3 == 0:
        result.append("emu")
      result.append(word)

    #If sentence is 3, 6, 9, etc letters long add emu to the end
    if n % 3 == 0:
      result.append("emu")

    return " ".join(result)

elif lang == 'EMU':
    sentence = ' '.join(sentence)

    #Get rid of mu and emu
    sentence = sentence.replace('mu', '')
    sentence = sentence.replace('e ', '')

    #Move the first letter to the end of the word
    return " ".join([words[1:] + words[0] for words in sentence.split()])
```

Comment: Try the English word `much` And it’s result `hmucmu`

Comment: Ahh I understadn now

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fixed code. In the elif lang == "EMU" statement

```
    for idx, word in enumerate(sentence):
      if idx > 1 and idx % 3 == 0:
        sentence.remove(word)

    sentence = " ".join([words[:-2] for words in sentence])
    sentence =  " ".join([words[1:] + words[0] for words in sentence.split()])
    print(sentence)
```

Comment: Editing a list while enumerating over it is Bad™.

Comment: Try this: `print(' '.join([w[1:-2] + w[0] for i,w in enumerate(sentence) if i % 4 != 3]))`